# Struggling with learning solr

Tags: solr

I am in the process of redesigning one of our companies site. My boss wants to play around with the idea of replacing all of our navigation with a search box.. the search box should be able to query any of our tables of unrelated data.

So right now I am trying it with 5 tables.

Products
Manufacturers
Category
Ingredients
Uses

So should be able to lookup a product name, a manufacturer name, a category name, an ingredient name, or a use name

When I retrieve the results. if the user clicked on a manufacturer search result.. It will take them to a manufacturer page that lookups all products for that manufacturer. 
When clicks on a product page.. link will take them to that actual product information.
Ingredient will take them to a page that will show all products containing that ingredient.

Anyways here is my data config

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx" user="xxx" password="xxx" />
    <document>
        <entity name="manufacturer" transformer="TemplateTransformer" pk="manNum"
            query="SELECT manNum, manName FROM manufacturer
                WHERE active = 1">
            <field column="id" name="id" template="MAN-${manNum}" />
            <field column="type" template="manufacturer" name="type"/>
            <field column="manName" name="text"/>       
            <field column="manNum" name="manNum"/>
        </entity>

        <entity name="product" transformer="TemplateTransformer"
            query="SELECT products.prodNum, products.prodName as text, m.manName FROM products  JOIN man m USING (manNum) 
                WHERE products.active = 1
                AND (hideWeb = 0 or hideWeb IS NULL)">
            <field column="id" template="PROD-${products.prodNum}" name="id"/>
            <field column="type" template="product" name="type"/>
            <field column="text" name="text"/>
            <field column="manName" name="manName"/>
        </entity>


        <entity name="ingredients" transformer="TemplateTransformer" pk="id"
            query="SELECT id, text FROM inglist WHERE sort != ''">
            <field column="id" name="id" template="ING-${inglist.id}"/>
            <field column="type" template="ingredient" name="type"/>
            <field column="text" name="text" />
        </entity>

        <entity name="uses" transformer="TemplateTransformer" pk="id"
            query="SELECT id, text FROM useslist">
            <field column="id" name="id" template="USE-${id}"/>
            <field column="type" template="use" name="type"/>
            <field column="text" name="text"/>
        </entity>

        <entity name="categories" transformer="TemplateTransformer" pk="id"
            query="SELECT id, textShow as text FROM categorylist">
            <field column="id" name="id" template="CATEGORY-${id}"/>
            <field column="type" template="category" name="type"/>
            <field column="text" name="text"/>
        </entity>


    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

And my schema..

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="text"          indexed="true"  stored="true" type="text"/>
    <field name="type" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
    <field name="manName" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
    <field name="manNum" type="string" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
</fields>
```

Now perhaps I am not doing this the right way... and there may be a better way to handle this.

Anyways the problem I am running into right now is that I am getting the error missing required field "id". Now products query and manufacturer query does not have an id column in the select.. but I thought the transform query should take care of it? If I do the select prodNum as id .. then all the ids are overwritting each other.

Now I could probably concat it in the actual query.. and will do so as a last resort, but would like to know what I am doing wrong with this solution.

**EDIT**
Nevermind, it was just a noob issue, for some reason I was thinking that the template variable was refering to the table name in the SQL not the entity name, 
So I replaced all of the 
    
With

And it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Was a noob issue,

for some reason I was thinking that the template variable was refering to the table name in the SQL not the entity name.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing the table-specific ID with a distinct character or string is a good idea. I do it in the SQL, which allows me to check the behavior outside of Solr.

```
select 
concat('b',cast(b.id as char)) as id,
...
```

Comment: It's just that I have seen other solutions on here that suggest using my original method, but can't get it working

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
<entity name="GG-Boryslaw-1939-Phonebook" 
         transformer="TemplateTransformer,DateFormatTransformer"
         pk="id"
         query="SELECT * FROM boryslaw_1939_phonebook">
     <field column="record_id" template="GG-Boryslaw-1939-Phonebook-${GG-Boryslaw-1939-Phonebook.id}" />
     <field column="record_type" template="phonebook" />
     <field column="record_source" template="Boryslaw Phonebook (1939)" />
     <field column="record_date" template="${GG-Boryslaw-1939-Phonebook.Year}" dateTimeFormat="yyyy" />
     ...etc...
</entity>
```